# SharePoint 2013-New changes are not reflecting in existing pages (its using visual studio custom page layout)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Can anyone help in below scenario?

1-Before some time I created and deployed visual studio custom page-layout in production.

2-Users created some pages using that page layout and add content.

3-Now I have done some enhancement in that and deployed again

4-If I am creating new page its showing  changes but existing pages not showing that changes??

Comment: You might use powershell to update the existing pages like in [this example](https://jakejacobsen.net/2011/04/06/powershell-script-for-updating-page-layouts-in-a-site-collection/)

Answer (score 1):

Try deactivating and reactivating the feature that contains the layouts.